# If I want to create a file every 12 hours, how can I compare it with the old one with bash

Tags: bash, shell

I want to monitor new subdomains with bash, so I want to scan subdomains every 12 hours automatically with **cron**.
Then compare the new text file with the old one to see if there is any difference. if I make the script output every time with `"$(date '+sube_%I:%M-%p_%d_%m_%Y')"` How can I compare it with the old one with bash?

Comment: Did you change the file? If not, you can use `ls` or `find` to sort files by date, so you can get easily the two last files. Note: for such tasks, we tend to use the inverse format (ISO format) YYYY-MM-DDTHH:SS, so that files are already sorted, and easy also to look for specific file or to delete old files. You may need this, if the datum of file change (some eidtors mangle also creation date)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Oops, very good spot. Deleted my answer for editing while I ensure that the filenames are correctly sorted by date... (can be done with `sort` and appropriate field specifiers)

Comment: @alaniwi: both `find` and `ls` have options to sort files by date. But I didn't include the options, because Mac, BSD, and GNU/Linux version are possibly different.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks - I've included both a `sort` option and an `ls -t` option.

Answer (score 3):

I'm understanding the question to mean that the `"$(date '+sube_%I:%M-%p_%d_%m_%Y')"` is used as the filenames of the output files.

Your output files might not all be exactly 12 hours apart, depending how long the cron job took to run, and at what stage of processing the filename is generated.  For example, you might have:

```
sube_07:37-pm_21_07_2020
sube_07:37-am_22_07_2020
sube_07:38-pm_22_07_2020
sube_07:37-am_23_07_2020
```

so it will be best to find the second-from-last and last files by listing files in the directory, rather than rely on trying to compute the exact timestamps.

```
final_two=$(ls sube_??:??-??_??_??_???? | sort -k1.21,1.24 -k1.18,1.19 -k1.15,1.16 -k1.12,1.13 -k1.6,1.10 | tail -n 2)
```

The sorting here is by year, month, day, am/pm, then hh:mm (fortunately a lexical sort on 'am' vs 'pm' will also be chronological), based on these character positions:

```
sube_07:37-am_23_07_2020
123456789012345678901234
         1         2
```

Or instead you could rely on the modification times of the output files rather than the timestamp in the filename, provided that nothing wrote to these subsequently:

```
final_two=$(ls -t sube_??:??-??_??_??_???? | tail -n 2)
```

As an aside, if you can choose a different output filename, then it will be better to choose one that is already in sorted order, for example: `$(date '+sube_%Y%m%d.%H%M')` which gives `sube_20200723.1937` etc.

Regarding the wildcard pattern, this version is fairly paranoid about excluding irrelevant files, but maybe the pattern `sube_*` will suffice.

Maybe also check that you actually found two files:

```
if [ $(echo $final_two | wc -w) -ne 2 ]
then
    # handle this case...
fi
```

You can then do:

```
this_one=$(echo $final_two | cut -d' ' -f2)
previous_one=$(echo $final_two | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

(We know that the filenames in question do not include any spaces etc, so we do not need to worry about that here.)

Once you have the two filenames, then you can do your comparison:

```
if ! diff -q $this_one $previous_one > /dev/null
then
    # there is a difference - do whatever...
fi
```

Putting this together for convenience, in practice you might prefer to write the first `if` test the other way round, so that the case where it can't find two output files is handled by an `else` block:

```
final_two=$(ls -t sube_??:??-??_??_??_???? | tail -n 2)
if [ $(echo $final_two | wc -w) -eq 2 ]
then
    this_one=$(echo $final_two | cut -d' ' -f2)
    previous_one=$(echo $final_two | cut -d' ' -f1)
    if ! diff -q $this_one $previous_one > /dev/null
    then
        # there is a difference - do whatever...
    fi
else
    # handle the case where we could not find two files
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

[man 1 diff](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html) is your friend. `diff` does exactly what you are asking to do. It compares the contents of two file (or entire directories of files) and details what changed between each file from old to new versions. Using the `-q` option will output only when files differ. You can redirect that to `/dev/null` to silence all output and use the return to make the determination, e.g.

`diff` returns `0` (true) if the files are the same, `1` otherwise. (which is why the return is negated with `!` in the test below) A simple

```
if ! diff -q old new > /dev/null; then 
    echo "files differ"
fi
```

Will tell you if the files `old` and `new` differ. If you want to act in both cases -- when the files are the same or when they are different, you can use:

```
if diff -q old new > /dev/null; then
    echo "files are the same"
else
    echo "files differ"
fi
```

Using a compound command can provide the same test for difference in short-hand version

```
diff -q old new > /dev/null || echo "files differ"
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you, the main point of the question is how can the file that the script is created compared in the same time with the old one automatically. I want a script to do the 2 jobs

Comment: I am a bit confused there. If your script creates a new file, then using the filenames with `diff` will do. If your script outputs the contents of a file you want to immediately compare the output to the old file, you can use *process substitution* to read from `stdin` like `diff -q old <(./somescript)`  Can you edit and provide examples of the filenames or where they come from so I can understand why we are not looking at an `old` and `new` file situation?

Comment: If you are talking about a script that automatically wakes up every 12 hours and does the comparison, then you will either use `cron` or `systemd.timers` depending on what your system uses to fire the script that does the comparison every 12 hours.